# Azure Functions ServiceBus Trigger Scaling Behavior

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

We are currently running load tests on our Azure Function App but the throughput is not what we expected.

There are multiple functions in the Function App but the ones with the most traffic are one with an Event Hub Trigger and one with a Service Bus Trigger consuming messages from a Session-Enabled Queue.

When the system is under load, Messages in the Session-Enabled Queue wait for up to 10 Minutes in the queue until they get processed by the consuming Function.

I know there are some settings in host.json to tune this behavior but it's still far from what we expect.

This is our host.json

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "serviceBus": {
      "prefetchCount": 100,
      "sessionHandlerOptions": {
        "autoComplete": true,
        "messageWaitTimeout": "00:00:30",
        "maxAutoRenewDuration": "00:55:00",
        "maxConcurrentSessions": 200
      },
      "batchOptions": {
        "maxMessageCount": 1000,
        "operationTimeout": "00:01:00",
        "autoComplete": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So i would expect the Function App to process up to 200 Sessions concurrently but in fact, although the Function Runtime provisions lots of instances, most of them seem to sit there and idle out. So to me it seems there is still another setting limiting the througput of the Function App.

[image: Application Insights Monitoring]

I know it would improve performance if we would split the functions to separate Function Apps but as the load on the both functions is quite similar my plan was to postpone this step to a later stage and still get acceptable throughput with a single Function App.

We are using Azure Functions 3 on .NET Core 3.1 with

- Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions 1.1.0
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus 5.0.0
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.EventHubs 5.0.0

on a Windows Consumption Plan.

Thank you for any hints on how to achieve acceptable throughput.

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that handling Batch Messages (receiving ServiceBusMessage[] instead of single instances) in the ServiceBus-Triggered Function along with enabled Sessions has a massively negative impact on scalability.

After changing this to single instances, the behavior of the system was as expected and the sessionHandlerOptions in host.json were respected.

I am wondering though what's the reason for this. I guess it could be related to the circumstance that Azure Function Instances lease a number of sessions from Service Bus to process but could not find anything in the documentation on that.

Comment: This is off topic but I am looking for a way to deliver same message to all scaled out instances via a queue trigger, service bus trigger or by some other means. My intention is to invalidate a localized cache in the function app upon a trigger. Is there a way to do that sort of thing without centralizing the cache?

Comment: So you are having local in-memory caches per function-host instance and want to invalidate them? Well i think you could achive this by using servicebus topics (offering pub/sub) and probably use the Azure ServiceBus SDK directly to register for messages received via the topic.
But i think a distributed cache like redis would be much more efficient in this regard. Having local in-mem caches would also increase memory consumption per function which you pay for (at least when on consumption plan) and show inferior cache hit rate.

Comment: Yeah I agree, it's not the best caching model. Thanks for the idea, I haven't used Azure Service Bus so when I read your question, I thought that's not gonna work too. But now I see it has a trigger mechanism as well as pub/sub. I should read up on it more. Thanks!

Comment: Replying to your question: I think the reason is that your scenario (IsBatched=true and IsSessionEnabled=true) is not covered in this table: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-target-based-scaling?tabs=v5%2Ccsharp#service-bus-queues-and-topics
I read elsewhere that when target-based scaling fails, it falls back to the old incremental scaling

Comment: @Zenuka Very interesting information, thanks! According to the Azure Docs Git History, Target Based Scaling was introduced in 2023 but maybe some ancestors of that functionality were already present in the Azure Function Codebase back in 2021 :)